# formatting iso-8601 date string

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

i am receiving events from several facebook fan pages in my ios app, and the response contains a field start_time, which is in ISO-8601 format. However, I have noticed that for some pages I get offsets in this string, but for some i dont. They might look like any one of the three, 2013-01-13T11:00:00, 2013-01-25T21:00:00+0530 or just the date 2013-02-03. How do i detect the format and format it into a more readable format with date and time in the user's time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the string for the "T" or the "+" given you know for sure those are the only 3 possibilities:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-01-13T11:00:00";

if (([dateString rangeOfString:@"T"].location != NSNotFound) && ([dateString rangeOfString:@"+"].location != NSNotFound))  {

    NSLog(@"found T and + in dateString: %@", dateString);
    //set date format accordingly...

} else if (([dateString rangeOfString:@"T"].location != NSNotFound) && ([dateString rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound)) {

    NSLog(@"only found T in dateString: %@", dateString);
    //set date format accordingly...

} else {

    NSLog(@"didn't find T or + in dateString: %@", dateString);
    //set date format accordingly...
}
```